# Round number to 10 in Bash

Tags: bash, numbers, rounding

I made a simple function where the result is e.g. 64.998472747. Is there a way this can be rounded up to 60? If it is 65.998472747 to be rounded to 70? Is this possible in Bash?

```
light=62.998472747
printf "$.0f" "$light"
```

So my function only rounds to a whole number. In this case it is going to round it to 63.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use awk like this:

```
awk -v n='64.998472747' 'BEGIN{print int((n+5)/10) * 10}'
60

awk -v n='67.998472747' 'BEGIN{print int((n+5)/10) * 10}'
70

awk -v n='95.0' 'BEGIN{print int((n+5)/10) * 10}'
100

awk -v n='94.99' 'BEGIN{ print int((n+5)/10) * 10}'
90
```

To make it generic, you can pass divisor as an argument and make a utility function as:

```
round() { awk -v n=$1 -v d=$2 'BEGIN{print int((n+d/2)/d) * d}'; }
```

Then call it as:

```
round 95.0000000001 10
100

round 94.9999 10
90

round 94.9999 1
95

round 95.5000000001 1
96
```

Comment: I was searching for so long to find a solution. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked explicitly for a **solution in `bash`**, here it is:

```
round10() {
    echo $(( ((${1%.*}+5)/10)*10 ))
}
```

For example:

```
$ round10 64.998472747
60
$ round10 65.998472747
70
$ round10 3.14
0
$ round10 6.28
10
```

We're using [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to first strip suffix decimals after the dot, in combination with [Arithmetic Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) to perform (now) integer arithmetic.